# SQLite two columns from table joined on same other table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have the following structure:

```
T1{id,person1,person2}

T2{id,name}
```

`T1.person1` and `T1.person2` are ids from `T2.id`

For a single column I do: `select T2.name from T1 left join T2 on T1.person1=T2.id`.

How can I get the name of both `person1` and `person2` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join the table twice:

```
SELECT
  TA.name,
  TB.name
FROM T1
  LEFT JOIN T2 TA ON(T1.person1 = TA.id)
  LEFT JOIN T2 TB ON(T1.person2 = TB.id)
```

Comment: It's that simple, huh? Thank you, ain.